# Node - build a tree recursively with API data

Tags: node.js, recursion, tree

I need to build a tree like structure using data from an API.

The structure i start with is as follows:

```
{
   "type": "group",
   "id": 1,
   "name": "rootGroup",
   "members": [],
}
```

There will always be a root group as the base of the tree.

I have a function named getMembersInGroup(groupId) which is an API call and returns something like:

```
[
  {
   "type": "group",
   "id": 77,
   "name": "IT group",
  },
  {
    "type": "user",
    "id": 40,
    "name": "John"
  }
]
```

Members can either be of type user or another group. So a user would look like:

```
{
  "type": "user",
  "id": 40,
  "name": "John"
}
```

If it's another group it needs to recursively fetch those until there are only users or empty array left in members.

Any group can have users at any level with the tree.

A mock of getMembersInGroup:

```
const getMembersInGroup = async (groupId) => {
  try {
    const members = await fetch.callApi('/groups/' + groupId + '/members');

    if (members) {  
      return members;
    }
    else {
      return [];
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}
```

The end result should look like this:

```
{
   "type": "group",
   "id": 1,
   "name": "rootGroup",
   "members": [
     {
       "type": "group",
       "id": 88,
       "name": "Some group",
       "members": [
         {
           "type": "user",
           "id": 231,
           "name": "SALLY"
         },
         {
           "type": "user",
           "id": 232,
           "name": "Henry"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "type": "user",
       "id": 41,
       "name": "Chris"
     }
   ],
}
```

I need help with the algorithm to create the tree.

Comment: Please provide in your question a non-trivial example of a populated data structure, an actual call of the function (i.e. the groupId) and the expected results for that call. You state that you **have** a function `getMembersInGroup`: please provide its definition and explain what the problem is with it. Essentially you are not asking a question, just stating things. What exactly is your question?

Comment: *"I need to build"*: is that the operation you are asking about? *"it needs to recursively fetch"*: or is that the operation you are asking about? If you have trouble building the structure, then are you asking about a more appropriate structure, that allows for searching more efficiently? If you have trouble to *find* data in that structure, then are you asking about how to implement recursion? It is not clear what the problem is here.

Comment: @trincot added more info to make it clearer... please let me know if I need to clarify further

Comment: I don't see an actual question. What is the problem you encountered while doing these tasks? What is the reason for posting? There should be a question somewhere, but I can't spot it...

Comment: @trincot I need help constructing the algorithm to create the tree recursively. I dont have all the data to begin with. So the top level group can via the API give me more groups or users. I need to investigate those groups until all users have been found in all child groups. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getMembersInGroup` function could look like this:

```
const getMembersInGroup = async (groupId) => {
    const members = (await fetch.callApi(`/groups/${groupId}/members`)) ?? [];

    for (const member of members) {
        if (member.type == "group") {
            member.members = await getMembersInGroup(member.id);
        }
    }
    return members;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
async function loadTree() {
    return {
        type: "group",
        id: 1,
        name: "rootGroup",
        members: await getMembersInGroup(1)
    };
}

loadTree().then(result =>
    console.log(result);
    // Work with the result ...
).catch(error =>
    console.log("error: ", error)
);
```

Demo with a mock implementation of `fetch.callApi`:

```js
// Mock for fetch.callApi 
const fetch = {
    mockData: [0,[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9],0,0,0,[10],0,0,[11,12],0,0],
    callApi(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const groupId = +url.split("/")[2];
            const children = this.mockData[groupId];
            if (!children) return reject("not found: " + groupId);
            const result = children.map(id => {
                const type = this.mockData[id] ? "group" : "user";
                return {type, id, name: type + "_" + id};
            });
            setTimeout(() => resolve(result), 50);
        });
    }
}

async function loadTree() {
    return {
        type: "group",
        id: 1,
        name: "rootGroup",
        members: await getMembersInGroup(1)
    };
}

const getMembersInGroup = async (groupId) => {
    const members = (await fetch.callApi('/groups/' + groupId + '/members')) ?? [];

    for (const member of members) {
        if (member.type == "group") {
            member.members = await getMembersInGroup(member.id);
        }
    }
    return members;
}

loadTree().then(result =>
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
).catch(error =>
    console.log("error: ", error)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
 const getMembersInGroup = async (groupId) => {
  try {
    const members = await fetch.callApi('/groups/' + groupId + '/members');

    if (members) {  
      foreach(member in members) {
        if (member.type == 'groups') {
          member.members = getMembersInGroup(member.groupid)
        }
      }
      return members;
    }
    else {
      return [];
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}
```

So you have the recursion only if it's a group type, otherwise the member is returned as is.